# How to have a Subject as a payload in an immutable Ngrx action?

Tags: ngrx, payload, subject

Use case: dispatch an action with a cold observable in the payload.
When an effect catches the action, it subscribes (through mergeMap, switchMap, whatever...) to this observable and send back another action. Classic Ngrx process.

```
export class ServicesStore {
  dispatchObservable(operation$: Observable<unknown>) {
    this.store.dispatch(serviceRequestAction({ operation$ }));
  }
}

export class ServicesEffects {
  serviceRequest$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(serviceRequestAction),
      mergeMap((action: ServiceRequestAction) => {
        return action.operation$.pipe(
          map((result) => {
            // send back an action with the result
          })
        );
      })
    )
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
this.servicesStore.dispatch(this.userService.getAll$());
```

It works well.

**But if this observable is a Subject** (say `MatDialog.open().afterClosed()`) **it will break the immutable action Ngrx rule**.
Because of the inner subscription, the Subject adds an observer into its internal structure, thus breaking the action immutability. It then triggers the [Ngrx runtime checks](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks#strictactionimmutability).

Of course I can disable these check, but I am looking for a better away around this.  For example, is there a way to clone a Subject ?
Or any other way to allow a Subject into the action payload ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK adding a subject to a NgRx Action isn't supported (if you want to keep the runtime checks enabled).
The classic NgRx process is that the effect results in a new action (popular ones are success and failure).